# Facing some difficulty in storing data into database using html form in django

Tags: python, django, database

I can't figure out why my registration form is not working it is unable to store data in database using django, i am getting no error the form works but data is not getting stored!

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import User

class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import RegistrationForm
from .models import User

def registration_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('registration:register')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    
    return render(request, 'registration/registration.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

app_name = 'registration'

urlpatterns = [
    path('registration/', views.registration_view, name='register'),
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User

admin.site.register(User)
```

Comment: maybe the form has some invalid inputs,use `if form.is_valid(): ... else: print(form.errors)` so you can see if the form has any errors

Comment: I tried it , not getting any error.